# Speed up Dynamic for graphical interface

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, performance-tuning, dynamic, gui-construction

I am trying to create a user interface where I can click on certain points in a set of data and save them into a list that can be used later in my code. The problem is it is currently sluggish. Is there a way to speed this up?

Also how can I make it so I can unclick a point I have previously click I remove it from the list?

```
testdata = Array[{#, 1 + #^2*RandomReal[]} &, 100];
clicks = {testdata[[1]], testdata[[-1]]};

Dynamic[ListPlot[{Button[Tooltip@#, clicks = Join[clicks, {#}]] & /@ 
testdata, Sort[clicks, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]}, {ImageSize -> 700, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic}]]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whole `ListPlot` is recalculated at each click because `clicks` value has changed, you can isolate `Dynamic` parts of graphics in `Epilog` to avoid that.

Using `EventHandlers` there will allow you to drop clicked points.

```
testdata = Array[{#, 1 + #^2*RandomReal[]} &, 100];
clicks = {testdata[[1]], testdata[[-1]]};


ListPlot[     
   Button[Tooltip @ #, AppendTo[clicks, #]] & /@ testdata,
   ImageSize -> 700, 
   PlotRange -> Automatic, 
   Epilog    -> {
     Dynamic[ 
       EventHandler[
         {AbsolutePointSize@12, Orange, Point@#}, 
         "MouseClicked" :> {clicks = DeleteCases[clicks, #]}
       ] & /@ clicks
     ]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick response. Long time lurker first time poster and it went better than I could have expected! Much smoother code now thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Nicklar I'm glad it fits your needs. Feel free to ask if anything is not clear. p.s. you can accept answers that are completely solving your problems, please take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).